# Query between dates only returns results if a selected date is equal or greater than date in data

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have two queries that are using a between clause to produce a date range, where the date is passed in through a VB.net program:

```
select
 w.plate,
 Description,
 Date_in,
 time_in,
 Date_out,
 Time_out,
 Date_out-Date_in as "Days on Site",
 Time_out-Time_in as "Duration on Site (Hrs)"
from tbl_stay S
inner join tblwhitelist W
on S.plate=W.plate
where Date_in between "1/06/2013" and "25/09/2013"
```

and

```
select
Plate,
Date_in,
Time_in,
Date_out,
Time_out,
Date_out-Date_in as "Days on site",
Time_out-Time_in as "Duration on site (Hrs)"
from tbl_stay
where plate not in (Select plate from tblwhitelist)
and date_in between "1/07/2013" and "1/08/2013"
```

For testing, i have a block of data that has the date "25/07/2013" for both in and out. These queries only seem to produce results if the **day** of the month is greater than the day mentioned in the data (25)

for example: the dates mentioned in the queries above:

```
Date_in between "1/06/2013" and "25/09/2013"
```

will yield a result, however

```
date_in between "1/07/2013" and "1/08/2013"
```

will not. even though the date included in the test data (25/07/2013) is within both of these ranges.

I am completely stumped. What could possibly be going on here? any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: what is the data tyoe for the field `date_in? the behavior u described seems as if its comparing strings

Comment: Does `between "25/06/2013" and "25/08/2013"` return results?

Comment: The format you're using depends on the MySQL settings. Try using one of the formats that don't depend on the settings, for example `... and date_in between DATE '2013-01-07' AND DATE '2013-01-08'`. More information on date formats is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Comment: Why not use a recognised date data type for storing dates?

Answer (score 1):

When you use double quotes you are comparing `text-strings`, not `dates`. Literal meaning of `01/07/2013` is less than `25/01/2013`, basically these strings are compared character by character. If you look at the first character in both strings, then `0` is less than `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not to use Between.

Separate that line in the `WHERE` clause into two and explicitly specify whether or not to include that date by using a `>=` or just a `>`.

`AND date_in > "1/07/2013"` or `date_in >= "1/07/2013"`

`AND date_in < "1/08/2013"` or `date_in <= "1/08/2013"`